# Android Service With Notification

Tags: android

I have one android application in i have to create a service that run 24 hours a day 
it also use xml parsing based on that data it gives notification on the particular time?

How can I do this?

Comment: You probably cannot get a service to reliably run _all_ the time unless you can deploy it as part of the Android installation with special low memory killer values.  But you may be able to get it to run most of the time.  Also be aware that this may kill battery life if it's a portable device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Service samples of the Service SDK. What you want to do is very well documented.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html